Reverse proxy entry for another web app running on same IP
I have some nginx app APP1 running on docker container with port exposed on 60001. Now there is another web App (APP2) running on docker container with port exposed on 60002 by another user account.
My nginx app is gateway app and it contains contain a link to APP2.
I cant add direct entry like http://IP:60002 due to firewall issue.
Now when i do reverse proxy  entry for APP2 in conf file, the page get displayed but there are many 404 error.
    server {
       listen 80;
       server_name yourdomain.com;
       root /var/www/html;

       # APP2
       location /APP2/ {
         proxy_pass http: //localhost:63000/;
         proxy_set_header Host $host;

         location /APP2/static/ {
            include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
            proxy_pass http: //localhost:63000/static/;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            access_log off;
            expires 30d;
        }
     }

in frontend, i observe when i click on link APP2
http://localhost:60001/static/css/main.ad3ff8cb.css file not found.
I am expecting it to http://localhost:60001/APP2/static/css/main.ad3ff8cb.css
